# Why is the alpha value of a Sprite in LibGdx 0.99607843 and not 1?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-design, sprites

I'm developing a game in LibGDX and one of my problems is related to the alpha value of a Sprite object.

If I create a new Sprite sprite object then `sprite.getColor().a` is equal to 0.99607843 and not 1. If I try to set `sprite.setAlpha(1)` it still sets it to 0.99607843. I also tried doing `sprite.getColor().a = 1;` but it still didn't work. My question is why is that? Is this just a limitation in LibGDX or am I doing something wrong?

(I put an issue on the official lib gdx github page. As of now the issue has been solved just because it was a duplicate of another issue, from what I get this problem is because of lib gdx, but the alpha still gets corrected on the shader side.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found in [NumberUtils](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/NumberUtils.java#L32-L36). Storing a color in a Java float can result in NaN bits being used, which Java is free to mangle, see Float#intBitsToFloat. libgdx uses 0-254 for alpha, then [scales it](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java#L144) in the shader to get it back into 0-255 range.